# Бесконечное создание проекта Unity

Tags: unity3d

В Unity версиях ниже 2020 beta, при создании проекта всё зависает на Importing, заходя в диспетчер задач, я вижу что unity editor просто не отвечает.Если же я закрываю создание проекта через диспетчер задач и пытаюсь запустить  его же , то в диспетчере задач показывается, что не отвечает уже проект.[image: Проблема]

Comment: Можно больше информации? Какая система, запущен ли движок через Hub или в одиночку? Это работает и с 2д и с 2д проектами?

Comment: Windows 10 64, запущен через Hub,2D проект.Адекватно unity работает только на альфа и бета версиях